# How do I actually create a custom UISearchBar?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit, uisearchbar, uicolor

I have been banging my head against a wall for a day now trying to figure out how to create a custom UISearchBar so I can get rid of the stock black search bar UIKit thinks I want. I've tried a few 'solutions':

**1. Customizing the appearance in the AppDelegate**

```
//default background color for search bars
UISearchBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchController.self]).tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#394C53")
```

This didn't work

**2. Subclassing `UISearchController` and `UISearchBar`**

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/) which didn't work

**3. Looping through subviews**

```
let results = DestinationSearchResultsTableViewController()
results.mapView = map
results.handleMapSearchDelegate = self

destinationSearch = UISearchController(searchResultsController: results)
destinationSearch!.searchBar.placeholder = "Where do you want to go?"
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    navigationItem.searchController = destinationSearch

    if let textfield = destinationSearch!.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {
            // Below is not what I want but it works
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }
} else {   
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationSearch!, animated: true)
}

destinationSearch!.delegate = self
destinationSearch!.searchResultsUpdater = results as UISearchResultsUpdating
```

This actually kinda works. It works really well if I use the `UIColor` predefined colors like `UIColor.white` `UIColor.red` etc. but it works really terribly if I want to use a specific color like this: [image]I tried using RGB and hex representations of the color above, but all I get is black.

**Here is what I want:**

I want to create my own UISearchBar with a left-aligned label and content textfield to the right as I have shown above.

Thanks

Comment: Hi There, I am stuck in a similar situation. Did you get this to work ?

Comment: @user3752049 unfortunately not yet

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So did you find any workaround or you had to abort it altogether ?